# Where can I host generated private documentation?

Tags: authentication, web-hosting, doxygen

I'm using [Doxygen](https://www.doxygen.nl/index.html) to generate documentation on a C++ project. I want to share this documentation with various team members without them having to build the docs themselves. In an ideal world, there's a service to privately host the static HTML that's generated from Doxygen, and gate it behind some sort of login. I think literally all this service needs to do is have some authentication middleware before serving the HTML. Just password protecting a directory is not good enough for what I'd like to do.

Does anyone know of a service like this that already exists? Am I taking the wrong approach?

Answer (score 2):

Azure has a static web app host available.

You can configure it so users must log in before anything is served up.
This is a bare bones config that will require people log into an app reg I made available to them, otherwise it will redirect to the azure ad login page.

We are already using Azure for our cloud needs, so this wasn't much to stand up for the documentation host.

[Custom authentication in Azure Static Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/authentication-authorization?source=recommendations&tabs=invitations)

[Authentication and authorization for Azure Static Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/authentication-authorization?tabs=invitations#block-an-authentication-provider)

```
{
    "auth": {
        "identityProviders": {
            "azureActiveDirectory": {
                "userDetailsClaim": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name",
                "registration": {
                    "openIdIssuer": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT_ID",
                    "clientIdSettingName": "AZURE_CLIENT_ID",
                    "clientSecretSettingName": "AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "routes": [
        {
            "route": "/*",
            "allowedRoles": [
                "authenticated"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "responseOverrides": {
        "401": {
            "statusCode": 302,
            "redirect": "/.auth/login/aad"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is a service that host static pages but provide the authentication functionality. I don't know if something like that exists and I have not found anything in a quick search.

However, there's another approach, much more simple. Just generate the documentation and upload it wherever you want that requires authentication (Google Drive, a private repository in GitHub or Bitbucket, etc). Give access to your team members and they will just have to keep it up to date with the remote one and open the `index.html` locally in their browsers.